# webpack could compile source file into output path

Tags: webpack

I've wrote a `webpack.config.babel.js` file, and I want to compile some code with babel with said file.

But after the code executed (with no warnings & errors), there's no compiled files in the output path.

With the command `webpack --config webpack.config.babel.js` (and an `.babelrc` of course), task compilation end successfully, and there's compiled files in 'dist/' folder, which is indicated in `webpack.config.babel.js`. But 'dist/' contain nothing.

**webpack.config.babel.js** (note: this file is written with es2015 syntax)

```
import path from 'path';
import webpack from 'webpack';

export default {
  devtool: '#source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client?noInfo=true&reload=true',
    path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/views/index.jsx'),
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
    filename: 'client.js',
    publicPath: '/dist',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
  ],
};
```

**source code**:
I'm trying to compile an bundle with webpack-dev-middleware & webpack-hot-middleware if I'm in development mode.

**server.js**:

```
const app = express();
app.use(express.static('./'));

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  setupDevServer(app); // this function contains setup.dev.server.js
}

....
```

**setup.dev.server.js** (**setupDevServer**() function above)

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
// import MemoryFS from 'memory-fs';
import webpackDevMiddleware from 'webpack-dev-middleware';
import webpackHotMiddleware from 'webpack-hot-middleware';
// import webpackServerConfig from './webpack.server.config.babel';
import webpackClientConfig from './webpack.client.config.babel';

export default function (express) {
  const clientCompiler = webpack(webpackClientConfig);
  // const serverCompiler = webpack(webpackServerConfig);

  express.use(
    webpackDevMiddleware(
      clientCompiler,
      {
        publicPath: webpackClientConfig.output.publicPath,
        noInfo: false,
      },
    ),
  );
  express.use(
    webpackHotMiddleware(clientCompiler),
  );
  // serverCompiler.outputFileSystem = new MemoryFS();

  clientCompiler.run( // for debug purpose
    (error, stats) => {
      console.log(error, stats); // and there will be an error 'can not run webpack twice'
    },
  );
}
```

There should be compiled files after `setupDevServer()` is executed. But there is nothing. There is no warning or error outputs in my console, and there is no compiled files in 'dist/' folder.

Comment: So which one is it? *there's compiled files in 'dist/' folder* or *'dist/' contain nothing*? You're contradicting yourself

Comment: With commmand `webpack --config webpack.config.babel.js`, it will compile source code into `dist/`. But if I compile it with code(webpack API), the compiled file will not appear in `dist/`.